# Сравнение периодов (время начала и окончания) элементов в JSON массиве

Tags: jquery, json

Есть массив json, как написать код, чтобы отобразить на странице элементы у которых периоды времени (начала и окончания) пересекаются?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
var periods = [
   {
 title: 'Иванов Иван',
 category: 'Категория 1',
        start : new Date('8/11/2018'),
        end : new Date('8/14/2018')
    }, {
     title: 'Петров Петр',
 category: 'Категория 1',
        start : new Date('8/12/2018'),
        end : new Date('8/16/2018')
    }, {
     title: 'Макаров Дмитрий',
 category: 'Категория 1',
        start : new Date('8/20/2018'),
        end : new Date('8/25/2018')
    }, {
     title: 'Мочалов Роман',
 category: 'Категория 2',
        start : new Date('9/1/2018'),
        end : new Date('9/10/2018')
    }, {
     title: 'Панкратов Сергей',
 category: 'Категория 2',
        start : new Date('10/1/2018'),
        end : new Date('10/10/2018')
    }, {
     title: 'Глухов Константин',
 category: 'Категория 2',
        start : new Date('10/2/2018'),
        end : new Date('10/5/2018')
    }
];
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Перечитайте Ваш вопрос. Вы поняли, что нужно сделать? Я - нет.

Comment: @Igor поправил, элементы у которых периоды времени (начала и окончания) пересекаются, фильтр по категории как на скриншоте.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var periods = [{
  title: 'Иванов Иван',
  category: 'Категория 1',
  start: new Date('8/11/2018'),
  end: new Date('8/14/2018')
}, {
  title: 'Петров Петр',
  category: 'Категория 1',
  start: new Date('8/12/2018'),
  end: new Date('8/16/2018')
}, {
  title: 'Макаров Дмитрий',
  category: 'Категория 1',
  start: new Date('8/20/2018'),
  end: new Date('8/25/2018')
}, {
  title: 'Мочалов Роман',
  category: 'Категория 2',
  start: new Date('9/1/2018'),
  end: new Date('9/10/2018')
}, {
  title: 'Панкратов Сергей',
  category: 'Категория 2',
  start: new Date('10/1/2018'),
  end: new Date('10/10/2018')
}, {
  title: 'Глухов Константин',
  category: 'Категория 2',
  start: new Date('10/2/2018'),
  end: new Date('10/5/2018')
}];



var pairs = [];
for(var i = 0; i < periods.length - 1; i++) {
  for(var j = i + 1; j < periods.length; j++) {
    var p1 = periods[i], p2 = periods[j];
    if (p1.category != p2.category)
      continue;
      
    if(!(p1.start > p2.end || p2.start > p1.end)) {
      pairs.push([i, j]);
    }
  }
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(pairs));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Igor огромное спасибо, все оказалось проще, чем я думал.